# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout(Kotlin)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-room

I have a trouble with a error "E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout" for 2 days...
Please help me what causes this error...
I already checked that getItemCount function return 1 result(Because the ProductEntity database only have 1 data)
Thank you in advance!!

[ProductActivity.kt]

```
package com.example.trymakeapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.trymakeapp.databinding.ActivityProductBinding
import com.example.trymakeapp.databinding.ItemProductBinding
import com.example.trymakeapp.db.AppDatabase
import com.example.trymakeapp.db.ProductDao
import com.example.trymakeapp.db.ProductEntity


class ProductActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityProductBinding
    private lateinit var db: AppDatabase
    private lateinit var productDao: ProductDao
    private lateinit var productList : ArrayList<ProductEntity>
    private lateinit var adapter : ProductRecyclerViewAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityProductBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        db = AppDatabase.getInstance(this)!!
        productDao = db.getProductDao()

        getAllProductList()


    }

    private fun getAllProductList() {
        Thread {
            productList = ArrayList(productDao.getAll())
            setRecyclerView()
        }.start()
        println("#####")

    }

    private fun setRecyclerView() {
        runOnUiThread {
            adapter = ProductRecyclerViewAdapter(productList)
            binding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter
            binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@ProductActivity)

        }

    }
}
```

[ProductRecyclerViewAdapter.kt]

```
package com.example.trymakeapp

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.trymakeapp.databinding.ItemProductBinding
import com.example.trymakeapp.db.ProductEntity
import java.util.ArrayList

class ProductRecyclerViewAdapter(private val productList : ArrayList<ProductEntity>)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductRecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
    inner class MyViewHolder(binding: ItemProductBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        val product_idx = binding.productIdx
        val product_name = binding.productName
        val product_price = binding.productPrice
        val product_img = binding.productImg
        val root = binding.root
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val binding : ItemProductBinding =
            ItemProductBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val productData = productList[position]
        holder.product_idx.text = productData.idx
        holder.product_name.text = productData.name
        holder.product_price.text = productData.price.toString()


    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return productList.size
    }

}
```

[MainActivity.kt]

```
...
...
btn3.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, ProductActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

Comment: It should be possible to workout why this problem happens by debugging the app. If you're using Android Studio then [this](https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts-v2/unit-1-get-started/lesson-3-testing,-debugging,-and-using-support-libraries/3-1-c-the-android-studio-debugger/3-1-c-the-android-studio-debugger.html) can really help understand how the tool works which should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the initialization in the `onCreate` method:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityProductBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    db = AppDatabase.getInstance(this)!!
    productDao = db.getProductDao()

    binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    adapter = ProductRecyclerViewAdapter(arrayListOf())
    binding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter

    getAllProductList()
}
```

And edit your `setRecyclerView` method like this (You can remove the `adapter` and `productList` global variables):

```
private fun setRecyclerView(productList: ArrayList<ProductEntity>) {
    runOnUiThread {
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = ProductRecyclerViewAdapter(productList)
    }
}
```

**EDIT** 
To handle the fact that data are not displayed. Try to use `LiveData` to observe its changes:

```
@Dao
interface ProductDao {
    @Query("select * from ProductEntity")
    fun getAll() : LiveData<List<ProductEntity>>
}
```

Then observe changes in the `getAll` method using `observe`:

```
 private fun getAllProductList() {
    productDao.getAll().observe(this) {
        setRecyclerView(ArrayList(it))
    }
}
```

Comment: still same error occured...

Comment: Try with edited answer..

Comment: Thank you so much! no more error occured!! However the data is not showing.. Is that the problem with layout xml?

Comment: Try with the edited answer